# Gradle: Is there a way to disallow version ranges in transitive dependencies?

Tags: gradle

When I've declared a snapshot repository in my Gradle configuration, is there a way to prevent transitive dependencies with version ranges from resolving to SNAPSHOT versions?  Alternatively, can I completely forbid version ranges in transitive dependencies?  For example, consider this very simple Gradle project:

```groovy
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/'
    }
}

apply plugin: "java"

dependencies {
    compile "org.reactfx:reactfx:1.4"
    compile "org.fxmisc.undo:undofx:1.0.1"
}
```

This will result in a version conflict and resolution since `undofx` depends on `reactfx` with version `[1.4,1.5)` (the most recent 1.4.x version available).  Here is the dependency insight for `reactfx`:

```plain
gradlew dependencyInsight --dependency reactfx
```

```plain
org.reactfx:reactfx:1.4.1-SNAPSHOT (conflict resolution)

org.reactfx:reactfx:1.4 -> 1.4.1-SNAPSHOT
\--- compile

org.reactfx:reactfx:[1.4,1.5) -> 1.4.1-SNAPSHOT
\--- org.fxmisc.undo:undofx:1.0.1
     \--- compile
```

Maven will also resolve `reactfx:1.4.1-SNAPSHOT` as the dependency for `undofx`.  However, it appears that once the `reactfx` dependency is added to the project, Maven resolves the conflict by using the version I've declared as a first level dependency.  Here's the Maven POM I used to test it:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>example</groupId>
    <artifactId>example</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>maven-central</id>
            <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>oss-snapshots</id>
            <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.fxmisc.undo</groupId>
            <artifactId>undofx</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.reactfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactfx</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

That's also the sort of resolution behavior I was expecting from Gradle, but only based on assumption.  I figured if `undofx` allows any `1.4.x` version of `reactfx` and the only other declared version of `reactfx` falls in that range, the conflict would be resolved by using my declared version.

However, I'm less interested in the conflict resolution than in failing the build if any transitive dependencies are using ranged versions.  I'd prefer to identify those dependencies and set them to specific versions.  I don't think I'd have noticed this one using a version range if I hadn't created the above conflict.

What's the easiest way to identify and deal with transitive dependencies using version ranges?

### Updated

Based on Peter's answer, here is a complete listing of the code I'm using to do this.  Take note that it's using features of the Gradle API that are marked as `@Incubating`.

```groovy
import org.gradle.api.artifacts.component.ModuleComponentSelector

if(!project.plugins.hasPlugin(JavaPlugin)) {
    apply plugin: "java"
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile "org.fxmisc.undo:undofx:1.0.1" // depends on reactfx:[1.4,1.5)
}

configurations {
    //noinspection GroovyAssignabilityCheck
    all {
        /*
        Once the dependencies in all configurations are resolved check the
        version of all module (not project) components that were resolved
        successfully.  Modules already using a forced version will be skipped.
         */
        incoming.afterResolve { // ResolvableDependencies
            it.resolutionResult.allDependencies { // DependencyResult
                if(it instanceof ResolvedDependencyResult
                        && it.requested instanceof ModuleComponentSelector) {
                    if(!it.selected.selectionReason.forced) {
                        checkVersion((ModuleComponentSelector) it.requested)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Check the version of the requested module and throw and exception if it's
 * using a version range.
 *
 * @param requested The module component to check.
 */
void checkVersion(ModuleComponentSelector requested) {
    def version = requested.version

    if(version.endsWith(")")
            || version.equals("LATEST")
            || version.equals("RELEASE")) {
        throw new GradleException(
                "${requested} uses a version range.  Try force.")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `configuration.getIncoming()` API to compare declared to resolved versions (e.g. in a `configuration.getIncoming().afterResolve()` hook), and fail if they aren't the same. To get the Maven conflict resolution behavior of "declared version wins" (rather than Gradle's "highest version wins"), you can use the `configuration.getResolutionStrategy().force()` API. To enforce that every version conflict is resolved explicitly (using `force()`), use `configuration.getResolutionStrategy().failOnVersionConflict()`. For API details, see the [Gradle Build Language Reference](http://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/index.html).

Comment: I updated the question with my solution based on that API.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.